# Writing bits of a byte to bin file

Tags: c

So I am attempting to write a stucture into a binary file. It works perfectly until I come up to writing only part of a byte. For data_offset, reserved, and ctl_bit, I only want to write the last 4, 6, 6 bits to the binary file. I'm not exactly sure where I am going wrong.

```
struct tcp_head
{
    unsigned short  source_port;    //16 bits
    unsigned short  dest_port;      //16 bits
    unsigned int    seq_num;        //32 bits
    unsigned int    ack_num;        //32 bits
    unsigned char   data_offset;    //4 bits
    unsigned short  reserved;       //6 bits
    unsigned short  ctl_bit;        //6 bits
    unsigned short  window;         //16 bits
    unsigned short  checksum;       //16 bits
    unsigned short  urgent_point;   //16 bits
};
```

When I write my file I have attempted to use bit-wise operators to mixed use.

```
    FILE *filePtr = fopen(filename, "wb");
    int i;

    if (!filePtr)
    {
        printf("\nError while writing file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    (*temp).data_offset = (*temp).data_offset << 4;
    (*temp).reserved = (*temp).reserved  << 10;
    (*temp).ctl_bit = (*temp).ctl_bit  << 10;


    fwrite(&(temp->dest_port), sizeof((*temp).dest_port), 1, filePtr);
    fwrite(&(temp->source_port), sizeof((*temp).source_port), 1, filePtr);
    fwrite(&(temp->seq_num), sizeof((*temp).seq_num), 1, filePtr);
    fwrite(&(temp->ack_num), sizeof((*temp).ack_num), 1, filePtr);
    fwrite(&(temp->data_offset), sizeof((*temp).data_offset), 1, filePtr);
    fwrite(&(temp->reserved),sizeof((*temp).reserved), 1, filePtr);
    fwrite(&(temp->ctl_bit), sizeof((*temp).ctl_bit), 1, filePtr);
    fwrite(&(temp->window), sizeof((*temp).window), 1, filePtr);
    fwrite(&(temp->checksum), sizeof((*temp).checksum), 1, filePtr);
    fwrite(&(temp->urgent_point), sizeof((*temp).urgent_point), 1, filePtr);



    fclose(filePtr);
```

Comment: fwrite works on a byte basis. there's no provision for bit offsets.  You'd have to build a complete 8bit byte from your individual bit values and write out that combined value. Remember: the f*() functions keep their offsets as integer bytes. there's no "offset 8.125" to signify having written a single bit.

Comment: Also, whenever you write a 16-bit or larger value, you're tying your file format to the endianness of your machine. If you want these files to be readable by something other than this same program, you have to deal with that. It's often better to copy structure members into a buffer and then write the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I only want to write the last 4, 6, 6 bits to the binary file.

And your code does:

```
(*temp).data_offset = (*temp).data_offset << 4;
(*temp).reserved = (*temp).reserved  << 10;
(*temp).ctl_bit = (*temp).ctl_bit  << 10;
```

`(*temp).data_offset << 4;` does a bit shift by 4. What you need is zero-out all the bits except the last 4. You can do that by using:

```
(*temp).data_offset = (*temp).data_offset & 0x0F;
```

Similarly, you need to use:

```
(*temp).reserved = (*temp).reserved  & 0x3F;
(*temp).ctl_bit = (*temp).ctl_bit & 0x3F;
```

That will zero out all the bits except the last 6.

It might be better for you to create temporary variables that store the transformed values and save the transformed values. Otherwise, you are modifying your object without being able to get back to the original state.

Comment: I replaced all of the shifts with & 0xXF, when I printed there right after the transform they were fine, however once I wrote them and printed them back from the read file I am having issues again.

Comment: @JarrodLofy, are they radically different from what you saved? Is there a pattern to the differences?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to write exact binary blocks like a TCP header, it's usually best to copy the structure members into a buffer first, then write the buffer. This will not only allow you to move individual bits around, but also lets to take care of things like endianness:

```
// Need htons(), etc.
#include <arpa/inet.h>
// Need uint16_t, etc.
#include <stdint.h>

. . .

unsigned char buf[20];

*(uint16_t *)buf = htons(temp->source_port);
*(uint16_t *)(buf + 2) = htons(temp->dest_port);
*(uint32_t *)(buf + 4) = htonl(temp->seq_num);
*(uint32_t *)(buf + 8) = htonl(temp->ack_num);
*(uint16_t *)(buf + 12) = ((temp->data_offset & 0x0F) << 12) |
                          ((temp->reserved & 0x3F) << 6) |
                          (temp->ctl_bit & 0x3F);
*(uint16_t *)(buf + 14) = htons(temp->window);
*(uint16_t *)(buf + 16) = htons(temp->checksum);
*(uint16_t *)(buf + 18) = htons(temp->urgent_point);
```

Now `buf` is a correctly-formatted network-order TCP header (assuming your structure was in "host" order), and can be written as a block of bytes.